# Raspberry Pi support Bootrom USB download?

Tags: usb, boot

I'd like to use Raspberry Pi WITHOUT binary loading from SDCard for simple test. The idea is build executable binary and download this binary via USB [from PC] into internal RAM [L2 cache] and execute from it. This require BootROM support USB dummy transaction between PC without loading any binary from SDCard. Can Raspberry Pi do this?

Thanks
Jason

Comment: If I understand your question you want to use the Pi like a microcontroller. I don't believe this is possible but this was recently announced and is still in beta by the Pi Foundation https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/ and https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/tree/master/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes